# C#:explicit conversion to address

Tags: c#, geocoding

While converting from address to longitude and latitude I used this code

```
Address[] addresses = geocoder.Geocode("1600 pennsylvania ave washington dc");
```

I get an error like;

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'Geocoding.Address[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing
>   a cast?)

I searched many sites but I didn't  get any proper answer  to covert between these types what explict conversion I have to make here? and how? please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
using System.Linq;

Address[] addresses = geocoder.Geocode("1600 pennsylvania ave washington dc").ToArray();
```

The `Geocode` method return an `IEnumerable<Array>` but you are trying to assign it to an array variable, which is why you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke `IEnumerable<Address>.ToArray()` to cast to an array.

```
Address[] addresses = geocoder.Geocode("1600 pennsylvania ave washington dc").ToArray();
```